# Can implementing programs to command line/path be dangerous?

Tags: command-line, path

Quite a few programs I use have an option for implementing itself to my computer's command line. I've currently disabled that feature on most of my programs (except node.js and a few others).

**Example from node.js:**
[image: Node.js - Added to PATH]

**I want to know if this implementation can be potentially dangerous.**

From what I know, the command line is basically the "root" of your system, and can allow the program to associate files with itself. This can be useful, like in coding software, to added in-program consoles. *But what are the downsides?*

**OS:** Windows 8.1 Pro

Comment: This cannot be answered without knowing the operating system.  Although it really doesn't matter there is no different between the command line application and running and an application with a gui.

Comment: Forgot to mention that. I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. If a program can be run from a GUI shell, such a desktop link or a file manager, then it can be run from a command line shell, although the latter gives access to the complete range of run options, which are not available in a GUI shell. If a user has execution permission for a program, then it can be run by whatever means the user has available.

Comment: @AFH As you said, running from a command line shell gives it more permissions. But can these extra permissions cause harm?

Comment: @DominatorX - It gives it the same permissions as the user unless the permissions are elevated of course which requires the permissions and the authentication of a user that has higher permissions the user.

Comment: @AFH I'm sticking to a scenario where **one** user has administrator privileges, and he/she is allowing the program to run from a command line.

Comment: I didn't say it gives more permissions: I said it gives access to all the run-time options, some of which may be construed as more dangerous than others, but a link can always be created to invoke the program with any particular option set in the run string.

Comment: You write "Quite a few programs I use have an option for implementing itself to my computer's command line" <-- Can you show screenshots of some examples of this? (googling the phrase you used - implementing program to command line - gives no responses). Show some screenshots and also, get the phrase word perfect.

Comment: (in terms of security, the command line is no more or less secure than the GUI. Either can be root and neither is necessarily root) But give screenshots of the message you are seeing from the programs, and then we can try to figure out what the programs mean.

Comment: @barlop Updated question with a screenshot from node.js.

Comment: @DominatorX absolutely no security risk at all to do that. It's rather like, if you want to run notepad, if it's in the path you just type notepad, if it's not in the path then you type c:\windows\system32\notepad   so it is for convenience to have a program in the path  If you don't use the fact that its in the path then you may as well not select that feature but no harm either way.

Comment: barlop and @AFH Can you both post answers (not in the comments section) so I can mark one of you as answer (or receive upvotes)?

Comment: Your question title doesn't make much sense. You made up a phrase "implementing programs to command line". If you don't know about a topic, then be triply sure to at least use the correct terminology and not make up your own. It is the screenshot that showed what you meant.

Comment: Your image and @barlop's answer cover the topic. My answer would not add anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely no security risk at all to add a program to the path. It's rather like, if you want to run notepad, if it's in the path you just type notepad, if it's not in the path then you type c:\windows\system32\notepad so it is for convenience to have a program in the path If you don't use the fact that its in the path then you may as well not select that feature but no harm either way

and in terms of security, the command line is no more or less secure than the GUI. Either can give root/administrative access and neither is necessarily giving root/administrative access.

and whether a program is in the path or not, a program's command line parameters/options can be accessed from the GUI(with a shortcut / icon), or from a command prompt/shell. Absolutely no difference in security there.